# encryption using AES in android, and decryption in Java

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have successfully encrypted password string in android and sent it to server where it is stored in database, now in order to implement "forgot-password" we need to decrypt that same "encrypted-password" in java.

used this library for encryption/decryption in android:
**com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1**

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of decrypting the existing password, its better you do one of the following things: 1. Generate a new password and send it to user wha should change this upon login. 2. Provide an interface to user to enter new password, encrypt this and replace it in your db.

Comment: Better to _hash_ passwords, not encrypt them.

Comment: encrypting passwords is really bad for security, you can find the encryption keys if you spend a few hours analysing the apk

Comment: @TiagoOliveira then what do you suggest ,that should be done for password security instead of encryption/decryption?

Comment: As @GriffeyDog said use hashing not encryption

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `password_hash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: This is the reason why banks and other secure websites never email you your password, they email you a link to reset your password-  because if they did security right even they don't know what your password actually is.

Comment: your suggestions seems great, but since I have no experience in these kind of stuff, could you guys please suggest some urls or sample code where this "hashing" or "Bcrypt" is done ?
Also, I cant change the flow as this is what the given requirement is, so android and java code needs to be in the same page in this password security stuff, same method should be able to run on both sides. @prerak sola

Comment: What language is the server code?, Java?

Comment: If you are asking about the api's developed, they are in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong (insecurely).

1. Do not encrypt the passwords on the client, send them in plain text to the server over HTTPS with a POST request.
2. Do not encrypt the passwords on the server, use a password secure hashing method (see my comment) that includes a salt and and iteration such that the time to hash is ~100ms. You will have no access to the original password, that is good because the attacker will not either. Yes there will be attackers, they will gain admin access, plan on it.
3. For password reset send a time-limited reset token to the user to use in creating a new password.

Note: Do use 2-factor authentication on the server and severly limit the number of people who have access.